# MapView: Use MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem to toggle map tracking state

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have added a MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem to my toolbar. But, clicking it does nothing.  So, I assumed I need to use `addTarget` like a normal UIBarButtonItem but that doesn't work either.

How can I attach a method to that button so that I can change `setUserTrackingMode:animated:`?

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackingItem = [[[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:mapView] autorelease];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"List", @"Detail", nil]] autorelease];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 30);
    [segmentedControl setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segmentedControl setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    UIBarButtonItem *segmentedButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *pageCurl = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl target:self action:nil] autorelease];
    pageCurl.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftFlex = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightFlex = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    self.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackingItem, leftFlex, segmentedButton, rightFlex, pageCurl, nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:mapView];   
[trackButton setTarget:self];
[trackButton setAction:@selector(track:)];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackButton, nil] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should initialize the MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem with this method:

```
– initWithMapView:
```

Refer to the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserTrackingBarButtonItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html