# How to detect when MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem is used

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, uibarbuttonitem

I'm currently trying to find a way to detect when the `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` is used, other than deal with the `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` delegate method.

I tried to setAction of the `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` to call my function (check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116811/mapview-use-mkusertrackingbarbuttonitem-to-toggle-map-tracking-state)), but of curse it removes the updating location action, which I don't want.

I don't find any delegate method triggered :/

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` has been assigned a `MKMapView` to operate on then the map view's delegate will receive `mapView:didChangeUserTrackingMode:animated:` when the tracking mode is changed (which is done by pressing that button).

ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:didChangeUserTrackingMode:animated: