# In Objective C, how to make a button with the location arrow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, location

I want to add a bar button item to my navigation bar. The button is used to show the users current location on map. How to make the button looks like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple...get an image that looks like that arrow. Add the bar button to your navigation bar and add the image to the bar button.

You can download an image like that at: http://www.glyphish.com

Comment: Instead of download an image, this post has an easier solution for me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116811/mapview-use-mkusertrackingbarbuttonitem-to-toggle-map-tracking-state